# What are the properties set for the message set of output message in the compute node?

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have set the below properties in the E SQL file of the computed node of the message flow.
I am trying to validate the content and value in the MQOutput node.

```
SET OutputRoot.Properties.MessageType = 'XMLNSC';
SET OutputRoot.Properties.MessageFormat = 'XMLNSC';
SET OutputRoot.Properties.MessageSet = 'K5KMMV8002001';
```

While debugging, the properties are set properly but we are getting below error just before writing the message in the output node.

> **Text:CHARACTER:Validation is enabled but pre-processed schemas cannot be           located for the specified message set**

What can be the possible error?

Comment: Are you trying to validate a message in the XMLNSC domain? Does that message set support that domain? Does it contain the message definitions? Btw when you want to validate messages in the XMLNSC domain, you don't need to specify MessageType and Format.

Comment: Yes I am trying to validate in XMLNSC domain. Mysteriously when I entered the message set name in the property instead of message set id it worked.